# Python multiline regex substitution

Tags: python, regex

I feel bad for asking *yet* another regex question, but this has been driving me crazy for the past week.

I am trying to use regular expressions in python to replace some text that looks like this:

```
text = """some stuff
line with text
other stuff
[code language='cpp']
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    printf("Hello");
}
[/code]
Maybe some
other text"""
```

What I want to do is capture the text inside the `[code]` tags, add a tab (`\t`) in front of each line and then replace all the `[code]...[/code]` by this new lines with the tabs prepended. That is, I want the result to look like:

```
"""some stuff
line with text
other stuff

    #include <cstdio>

    int main() {
        printf("Hello");
    }

Maybe some
other text"""
```

I am using the following snippet.

```
class CodeParser(object):
    """Parse a blog post and turn it into markdown."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.regex = re.compile('.*\[code.*?\](?P<code>.*)\[/code\].*',
                                re.DOTALL)

    def parse_code(self, text):
        """Parses code section from a wp post into markdown."""
        code = self.regex.match(text).group('code')
        code = ['\t%s' % s for s in code.split('\n')]
        code = '\n'.join(code)
        return self.regex.sub('\n%s\n' % code, text)
```

The problem with this is that it matches all the characters before and after the `code` tags because of the initial and final `.*` and when I perform the replacement, these are removed. If I remove the `.*`s, the re does not match anything anymore.

I thought this could be a problem with newlines, so I tried replacing all the `'\n'` with, say, `'¬'`, performing the matching, and then changing the `'¬'` back to `'\n'`, but I didn't have any luck with this approach.

If anyone has a better method of accomplishing what I want to accomplish, I am open to suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. 
Instead of regex.match, use regex.search. That way you can get rid of the leading and trailing `.*s`.

```
Try this:
    def __init__(self):
        self.regex = re.compile('\[code.*?\](?P<code>.*)\[/code\]',
                                re.DOTALL)


    def parse_code(self, text):
        """Parses code section from a wp post into markdown."""
        # Here we are using search which finds the pattern anywhere in the 
        # string rather than just at the beginning
        code = self.regex.search(text).group('code')
        code = ['\t%s' % s for s in code.split('\n')]
        code = '\n'.join(code)

        return self.regex.sub('\n%s\n' % code, text)
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have kept reading on the docs a little bit further down... It's [right there](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#match-versus-search)